# Building a virtualised cluster where the job sizes exceed the capacity of a single node

Tags: cluster-computing

We are currently building a cluster out of some old tech we have lying around. The job sizes we have exceed the capacity of the single nodes and we wanted to have the virtual cluster so that only the header node had an OS installed and the rest of the nodes were considered as one main machine where the processors and RAM are all pooled together. Is this at all possible? As you can tell, we're pretty new to clustered computing.

Thank you!

Comment: "Building a cluster"? A cluster is usually the software that manages the jobs, but it doesn't sound like you have any such software. At this point, it sounds like you're just building out your data-center (even if it's fairly small). The individual workers, whatever the software, are going to need to work using the full constitution of whatever job they're currently working on. So, in answer to your question, no. You're going to have to split-up the jobs into smaller units. Push the data into the DB and just keep the references in the job itself.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend a particular distribution (e.g. ROCKS) to install on the header node to virtualise the cluster?

Comment: It's highly subjective and is going to depend on what the requirements of your jobs are. Time for research or more-specific questions :) . If you're dealing with limited resources, stay away from Java. That should eliminate 90% of the options. If I were you, I'd consider writing something simple in-house (you might not be able to afford the overhead of a management layer and this might allow your solution to be tighter) or have some fun figuring-out OpenStack.